# Go to the specific url on clicking of a div in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am developing an angular mobile APP, where i wanted to go tho the specific url for eg: www.google.com on clicking of a particular div. but i am not able to do that as i am new to this angular world.

```
<div ng-click="goToGoogle('www.google.com');" class="" id="">
    <p class=""><span class="">Go to Google Full Web Site</span></p>
</div>
```

In controller Function

```
$scope.goToGoogle = function (url) {
    $scope.$apply( $location.path(url) );
}
```

Please help me to do that.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please paste the complete module code here or in a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller, have you passed in the $location service along with the scope?

**UPDATE**
Try passing the `$window` service.

```
$window.location.href = url;
```

You don't even have to use `$scope.apply` for it.

Comment: Yes i injected that $location object

Comment: Thanks scartag for the quick help. Now it is working, but i have to do the slight modification in the url i am passing i.e i add the "http://" with the parameter passed "ng-click="goToGoogle('http://www.google.com');"